# Getting a Django API call to respond with simple json

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This should be a really simple thing to do.... but I seem to be going round in circles - rather than return model data, I need to return a dataset calculated from several tables

I'm extending an existing app that has a suite of API calls & UI rendering.

- `Django` == 2.2.1
- `djangorestframework` == 3.9.3

The routing is defined thus:

```
router.register('issn', views.IssnDataSet, basename='issn')
```

(using `router = DefaultRouter()`)

The class is thus:

```
class IssnDataSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    lookup_field = 'resource__e_issn'  # looking through a relationship
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'id'
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)

    filterset_class = EntitlementFilterSet  # does clever user permissions filtering
    serializer_class = HackSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        data = dict()
        issn = self.kwargs.get('id')
        qs = Entitlement.objects
        ## Do filtering to get the subset we want
        for entitlement in qs.all():
            ## Do stuff to build the data dict from various relationships, deductions, and calculations
        return data

    # needed else it barfs for some reason
    @classmethod
    def get_extra_actions(cls):
        return []
```

and the serializer:

```
class HackSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return json.dumps(instance)
```

The `data` object that `IssnDataSet` creates is something like:

```
{'Accounting, Business & Financial History': {
    'title': 'Accounting, Business & Financial History',
    'p_issn': '0958-5206',
    'e_issn': '1466-4275',
    'dates': [
       {'start': '2005-01-01', 'end': '2005-12-31'}, 
       {'start': '2007-01-01', 'end': '2007-12-31'}, 
       {'start': '2006-01-01', 'end': '2006-12-31'}, 
       {'start': '2009-01-01', 'end': '2009-12-31'}, 
       {'start': '2011-01-01', 'end': '2011-12-31'}, 
       {'start': '2008-01-01', 'end': '2008-12-31'}, 
       {'start': '2011-01-01', 'end': '2011-12-31'}, 
       {'start': '2006-01-01', 'end': '2006-12-31'}, 
       {'start': '2009-01-01', 'end': '2009-12-31'}, 
       {'start': '1991-01-01', 'end': '1991-01-01'}, 
       {'start': '2010-01-01', 'end': '2010-12-31'}, 
       {'start': '2010-01-01', 'end': '2010-12-31'},
       {'start': '2008-01-01', 'end': '2008-12-31'},
       {'start': '2007-01-01', 'end': '2007-12-31'}
    ]}
}
```

Currently I'm getting an `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'model'` error

I've tried loads of different *solutions*, but none of them seem to work for me.

I've tried `GenericAPIView`, I've tried stuff with `return Response(_something_)`, I've tried more things from multiple thoughts on the web.... and I think I've just confuddled myself.

I suspect the actual solution is using techniques I've tried.... just with the *correct* sets :)

Help??

---

addendum: Request by `Shayan` - the relevant error-log output:

```
gunicorn_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [05/Jul/2021:07:36:19 +0100] "GET /api/issn/0958-5206 HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0"
gunicorn_1  | Internal Server Error: /api/issn/0958-5206/
gunicorn_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
gunicorn_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
gunicorn_1  |     response = get_response(request)
gunicorn_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
gunicorn_1  |     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
gunicorn_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
gunicorn_1  |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
gunicorn_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
gunicorn_1  |     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
gunicorn_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 116, in view
gunicorn_1  |     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
gunicorn_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
gunicorn_1  |     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
gunicorn_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
gunicorn_1  |     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
gunicorn_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in raise_uncaught_exception
gunicorn_1  |     raise exc
gunicorn_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
gunicorn_1  |     self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
gunicorn_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 401, in initial
gunicorn_1  |     self.check_permissions(request)
gunicorn_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 334, in check_permissions
gunicorn_1  |     if not permission.has_permission(request, self):
gunicorn_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/permissions.py", line 234, in has_permission
gunicorn_1  |     perms = self.get_required_permissions(request.method, queryset.model)
gunicorn_1  | AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'model'
gunicorn_1  | IssnViewSet.get_queryset start
gunicorn_1  | IssnViewSet.get_queryset issn = 0958-5206
gunicorn_1  | IssnViewSet.get_queryset : title = Accounting, Business & Financial History: 2005-01-01 2005-12-31
gunicorn_1  | IssnViewSet.get_queryset : title = Accounting, Business & Financial History: 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
gunicorn_1  | IssnViewSet.get_queryset : title = Accounting, Business & Financial History: 2006-01-01 2006-12-31
gunicorn_1  | IssnViewSet.get_queryset : title = Accounting, Business & Financial History: 2009-01-01 2009-12-31
gunicorn_1  | IssnViewSet.get_queryset : title = Accounting, Business & Financial History: 2011-01-01 2011-12-31
gunicorn_1  | IssnViewSet.get_queryset : title = Accounting, Business & Financial History: 2008-01-01 2008-12-31
gunicorn_1  | IssnViewSet.get_queryset : title = Accounting, Business & Financial History: 2011-01-01 2011-12-31
gunicorn_1  | IssnViewSet.get_queryset : title = Accounting, Business & Financial History: 2006-01-01 2006-12-31
gunicorn_1  | IssnViewSet.get_queryset : title = Accounting, Business & Financial History: 2009-01-01 2009-12-31
gunicorn_1  | IssnViewSet.get_queryset : title = Accounting, Business & Financial History: 1991-01-01 1991-01-01
gunicorn_1  | IssnViewSet.get_queryset : title = Accounting, Business & Financial History: 2010-01-01 2010-12-31
gunicorn_1  | IssnViewSet.get_queryset : title = Accounting, Business & Financial History: 2010-01-01 2010-12-31
gunicorn_1  | IssnViewSet.get_queryset : title = Accounting, Business & Financial History: 2008-01-01 2008-12-31
gunicorn_1  | IssnViewSet.get_queryset : title = Accounting, Business & Financial History: 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
gunicorn_1  | data: {'Accounting, Business & Financial History': {'title': 'Accounting, Business & Financial History', 'p_issn': '0958-5206', 'e_issn': '1466-4275', 'dates': [{'start': '2005-01-01', 'end': '2005-12-31'}, {'start': '2007-01-01', 'end': '2007-12-31'}, {'start': '2006-01-01', 'end': '2006-12-31'}, {'start': '2009-01-01', 'end': '2009-12-31'}, {'start': '2011-01-01', 'end': '2011-12-31'}, {'start': '2008-01-01', 'end': '2008-12-31'}, {'start': '2011-01-01', 'end': '2011-12-31'}, {'start': '2006-01-01', 'end': '2006-12-31'}, {'start': '2009-01-01', 'end': '2009-12-31'}, {'start': '1991-01-01', 'end': '1991-01-01'}, {'start': '2010-01-01', 'end': '2010-12-31'}, {'start': '2010-01-01', 'end': '2010-12-31'}, {'start': '2008-01-01', 'end': '2008-12-31'}, {'start': '2007-01-01', 'end': '2007-12-31'}]}}
```

Comment: Django Rest Framework 3.9.3 version is compatible with Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.* and you are using Python == 2.2.1. Make sure upgrading or degrading one another doesn't make a breaking change in the entire project and try it out.

Comment: @Shayan - Django  ">=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*", or python?

I'm running the service under **python** 3.7. In the docker instance, conda lists `Django  2.2.1` & `djangorestframework  3.9.3`; and python reports itself as `Python 3.7.9`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Can you give us the error log, please?

Comment: @Shayan - question now has error as addendum
(many thanks for this!)

Comment: get_queryset method returns a dictionary but it should return a queryset. If you don't want to return queryset and want to change data there, I'd suggest you to remove the get_queryset method, and override get method. This way, you can directly return an `Response` object with customized data you want.

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın - that gets me a 404 ( `"detail": "Not found."`) error.... ie, the query is path: `/api/issn/` changeable parameter `0958-5206`

(I'#m fairly sure I mucked around with the `@action` decorator - but I'll continue to fiddle

Comment: @CodeGorilla ModelViewSet has a list and retrieve methods. I think you should override one of them depending on if you're using the pk or not (seems like you use one, so override `retrieve`). And return a Response instance there. Also I see a flaw in your serializer, I think it'd be better to explicitly create a dictionary on your to_representation and build it there rather than just dumping it. Please try these and if problem still continues, update your question with new changes and we can help you further

Comment: Why did you use the `dict()` for data? As far as I'm concerned it should be a query set, not a dictionary. You are using a model view set but not returning an actual model and it's custom data. I may think it's better to use API view.

Comment: @Shayan You are correct - the Model View may be the distraction.... however I'm still struggling to understand APIViews too

(I'm returning a dict() because the data I'm returning does not map onto the models)